# How to generate grid of dots from image array with interval x?

Tags: python

Suppose I have an image 1000x1000, I want to put a red dot every 10 pixels. How to generate such an array?

```
M, N = 5, 8

x = np.linspace(0,1000,M+1)
y = np.linspace(0,1000,N+1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

positions = np.vstack([Y.ravel(), X.ravel()])

for x in positions:
    cv2.circle(img,(x[0], x[1]), 5, (0,255,0), 2)
```

[image]

Comment: why do you have ````M, N = 5, 8```` ? and is it every ten pixels in each dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
x = np.linspace(0,1000, 1000/10)
y = np.linspace(0,1000, 1000/10)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

positions = np.column_stack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()]).astype(int)

for (x,y) in (positions):
    cv2.circle(img,(x,y), 1, (0,0,255), -1)
```

The following two lines will create a linespace of 100 pixels with a space of 10 pixels in each dimension

```
x = np.linspace(0,1000, 1000/10)
y = np.linspace(0,1000, 1000/10)
```

Then, create a grid from the spaces using `np.meshgrid`. Then, create stacked columns from the raveled vectors of the grid. Make sure to convert your positions to `int`, since open cv accepts the center of your circle to be an `int`. Finally, use `cv2.circle` to plot the points, open cv accepts color as BGR so `(0,0,255)` will give you a red color. Since it's a point you use a radius of `1` and a thickness of `-1`.